# detecting contours of white object

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find the object which is painted white as shown in image attached 
I am using HSV color space to detect white color
I am not able to get the complete object, part of the object gets detected, though whole object is painted white Image from which I am trying to detect white object:
[image] .

This is what I am getting, only part of the object is getting detected

[image: Detected Image]

here is code I used

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

rawImage = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\user1\\calibration\\painted2.jpg') 
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(rawImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_white = np.array([0,3,240])
higher_white = np.array([255,5,255])
# getting the range of blue color in frame
white_range = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, higher_white)
cv2.imshow("White", white_range);cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Can anyone tell what is that I am doing wrong, and how can I find the complete object

Answer (score 2):

Try to adjust the color range:

```
lower_white = np.array([0,0,180])
higher_white = np.array([255,255,255])
white_range = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, higher_white)
plt.imshow(white_range, cmap='gray')
```

gives

[image]

Or you can filter right on `BGR` color space:

```
lower_white = (180,180,180)
higher_white = (255,255,255)
white_range = cv2.inRange(rawImage, lower_white, higher_white)
```

gives

[image]